How to run Wolfram kernel from under Windows service to export charts
I want to generate multiple charts using Wolfram as a chart generator. To do so I generate an input file, e.g.. example.m:
xy0 = {{ 0.000000*^+000, 9.665999*^+000 }, { 0.000000*^+000, 9.665999*^+000 }, { 0.000000*^+000, 9.665999*^+000 }, { 2.897797*^-005, 9.666303*^+000 }, { 2.897797*^-005, 9.666303*^+000 }, { 2.897797*^-005, 9.666302*^+000 }, { 5.795593*^-005, 9.666606*^+000 }, { 1.055085*^-003, 9.677055*^+000 }, { 1.055085*^-003, 9.677055*^+000 }, { 2.052213*^-003, 9.687493*^+000 }, { 2.052213*^-003, 9.687493*^+000 }, { 6.225104*^-003, 9.731056*^+000 }, { 1.461802*^-002, 9.818093*^+000 }, { 2.839114*^-002, 9.959225*^+000 }, { 2.839114*^-002, 9.959225*^+000 }, { 5.405902*^-002, 1.021654*^+001 }, { 7.617117*^-002, 1.043215*^+001 }, { 1.032835*^-001, 1.068872*^+001 }, { 1.168397*^-001, 1.081374*^+001 }, { 1.303959*^-001, 1.093655*^+001 }, { 1.674299*^-001, 1.126063*^+001 }, { 1.859470*^-001, 1.141632*^+001 }, { 2.044640*^-001, 1.156770*^+001 }, { 2.414980*^-001, 1.185738*^+001 }, { 2.672720*^-001, 1.204855*^+001 }, { 2.672720*^-001, 1.204855*^+001 }, { 2.930460*^-001, 1.223101*^+001 }, { 3.188200*^-001, 1.240467*^+001 }, { 3.445940*^-001, 1.256944*^+001 }, { 3.703680*^-001, 1.272522*^+001 }, { 3.961420*^-001, 1.287194*^+001 }, { 4.322201*^-001, 1.306193*^+001 }, { 4.682982*^-001, 1.323382*^+001 }, { 5.043762*^-001, 1.338744*^+001 }, { 5.404543*^-001, 1.352264*^+001 }, { 5.765323*^-001, 1.363932*^+001 }, { 6.126104*^-001, 1.373738*^+001 }, { 6.486885*^-001, 1.381676*^+001 }, { 6.847665*^-001, 1.387742*^+001 }, { 7.208446*^-001, 1.391934*^+001 }, { 7.569227*^-001, 1.394255*^+001 }, { 7.930007*^-001, 1.394706*^+001 }, { 7.930007*^-001, 1.394917*^+001 }, { 7.930007*^-001, 1.394917*^+001 }, { 7.839812*^-001, 1.394770*^+001 }, { 7.767656*^-001, 1.394734*^+001 }, { 7.857851*^-001, 1.394766*^+001 }, { 7.843703*^-001, 1.394768*^+001 }, { 7.837697*^-001, 1.394768*^+001 }, { 7.837953*^-001, 1.394768*^+001 }, { 8.123596*^-001, 1.394768*^+001 }, { 9.405913*^-001, 1.394768*^+001 }, { 1.068823*^+000, 1.394768*^+001 }, { 2.351140*^+000, 1.394768*^+001 }, { 3.633456*^+000, 1.394768*^+001 }, { 1.645662*^+001, 1.394768*^+001 }, { 2.927979*^+001, 1.394768*^+001 }, { 1.575115*^+002, 1.394768*^+001 }, { 1.575115*^+002, 1.394768*^+001 }, { 1.000000*^+002, 1.394768*^+001 }};
xy1 = {{ 0.000000*^+000, 1.048505*^+001 }, { 0.000000*^+000, 1.048505*^+001 }, { 0.000000*^+000, 1.048505*^+001 }, { 2.897797*^-005, 1.048473*^+001 }, { 2.897797*^-005, 1.048473*^+001 }, { 2.897797*^-005, 1.048473*^+001 }, { 5.795593*^-005, 1.048441*^+001 }, { 1.055085*^-003, 1.047347*^+001 }, { 1.055085*^-003, 1.047347*^+001 }, { 2.052213*^-003, 1.046252*^+001 }, { 2.052213*^-003, 1.046252*^+001 }, { 6.225104*^-003, 1.041659*^+001 }, { 1.461802*^-002, 1.032371*^+001 }, { 2.839114*^-002, 1.016984*^+001 }, { 2.839114*^-002, 1.016984*^+001 }, { 5.405902*^-002, 9.878385*^+000 }, { 7.617117*^-002, 9.622538*^+000 }, { 1.032835*^-001, 9.303026*^+000 }, { 1.168397*^-001, 9.140945*^+000 }, { 1.303959*^-001, 8.977357*^+000 }, { 1.674299*^-001, 8.523037*^+000 }, { 1.859470*^-001, 8.291965*^+000 }, { 2.044640*^-001, 8.058398*^+000 }, { 2.414980*^-001, 7.584130*^+000 }, { 2.672720*^-001, 7.248750*^+000 }, { 2.672720*^-001, 7.248750*^+000 }, { 2.930460*^-001, 6.909287*^+000 }, { 3.188200*^-001, 6.565980*^+000 }, { 3.445940*^-001, 6.219075*^+000 }, { 3.703680*^-001, 5.868817*^+000 }, { 3.961420*^-001, 5.515453*^+000 }, { 4.322201*^-001, 5.016076*^+000 }, { 4.682982*^-001, 4.511786*^+000 }, { 5.043762*^-001, 4.003275*^+000 }, { 5.404543*^-001, 3.491236*^+000 }, { 5.765323*^-001, 2.976364*^+000 }, { 6.126104*^-001, 2.459357*^+000 }, { 6.486885*^-001, 1.940913*^+000 }, { 6.847665*^-001, 1.421728*^+000 }, { 7.208446*^-001, 9.024980*^-001 }, { 7.569227*^-001, 3.839155*^-001 }, { 7.930007*^-001, 0.000000*^+000 }, { 7.930007*^-001, 0.000000*^+000 }, { 7.930007*^-001, 0.000000*^+000 }, { 7.839812*^-001, 0.000000*^+000 }, { 7.767656*^-001, 9.922125*^-002 }, { 7.857851*^-001, 0.000000*^+000 }, { 7.843703*^-001, 0.000000*^+000 }, { 7.837697*^-001, 0.000000*^+000 }, { 7.837953*^-001, 0.000000*^+000 }, { 8.123596*^-001, 0.000000*^+000 }, { 9.405913*^-001, 0.000000*^+000 }, { 1.068823*^+000, 0.000000*^+000 }, { 2.351140*^+000, 0.000000*^+000 }, { 3.633456*^+000, 0.000000*^+000 }, { 1.645662*^+001, 0.000000*^+000 }, { 2.927979*^+001, 0.000000*^+000 }, { 1.575115*^+002, 0.000000*^+000 }, { 1.575115*^+002, 0.000000*^+000 }, { 1.000000*^+002, -1.421352*^+003 }};
legends = { Velocity, Acceleration };
outputFile = "C:\\Wolfram\\Output\\38dbd4c1-5499-462a-a96f-4b8efb121814.png";
Export[outputFile, ListLinePlot[{xy0, xy1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 16, Bold, Black}, PlotLegends -> legends], "PNG"];

and then call GUI-less Mathematica kernel, math.exe using MathLink:
"-linkname 'C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\13.0\math.exe -mathlink' -linklaunch"
then:
"<< \"C:\\Wolfram\\Input\\a676f35e-f425-448d-9653-cfd1a65d014b.m\""
This is the piece of F# code that does that:
let linkArgs = $"-linkname '{kernelName.value} -mathlink' -linklaunch"

Logger.logTrace $"tryRunMathematicaScript - linkArgs: '%A{linkArgs}'."
let link = MathLinkFactory.CreateKernelLink(linkArgs)
Logger.logTrace $"tryRunMathematicaScript - link created."

try
    link.WaitAndDiscardAnswer()
    Logger.logTrace $"tryRunMathematicaScript - call to link.WaitAndDiscardAnswer() completed."

    // Wolfram wants "\\\\" for each "\\" in the path. Don't ask why.
    let scriptCommand = $"<< \"%s{i.toWolframNotation()}\"" // Use "<< file.m" to load the script.
Logger.logTrace $"tryRunMathematicaScript - scriptCommand: '%A{scriptCommand}'."
    link.Evaluate(scriptCommand)
    Logger.logTrace $"tryRunMathematicaScript - call to link.Evaluate(scriptCommand) completed."

    link.WaitForAnswer() |> ignore
    Logger.logTrace "tryRunMathematicaScript - call to link.WaitForAnswer() completed."

If I run the code as a regular EXE, then everything works file. No windows pop up (in contrast to MathLink.exe where you would see its icon temporarily appear) and the output file is generated.
However, if I run it under Windows service (I tried LOCAL SYSTEM account and running as some admin user - the result is the same), then the code hangs up on link.WaitForAnswer() and never logs the next line:
Logger.logTrace "tryRunMathematicaScript - call to link.WaitForAnswer() completed."

My guess is that even though math.exe is GUI-less, the evaluation of either Export or ListLine does require some GUI "pieces" (whatever they are) and so, since a Windows service has absolutely no GUI, this evaluation hangs up.
I could probably run math.exe directly using -script switch. However, I have doubts that that will work because it is math.exe that hangs up, not the link and nothing will change from math.exe point of view when running directly. Or so I think.
Is it possible to perform such export from under Windows service and if yes, then how?

I don't think this is really a problem of Wolfram Kernel, which is a console application ... How can I run an EXE program from a Windows Service using C#?

@Domen, yes, it is a problem as otherwise I wouldn't have asked this question. ListLinePlot needs to know on which monitor to draw. So, somewhere deep in Mathematica there must be a call to Windows API asking about the monitor, its resolution, etc. Console app can get that information, but Windows service cannot. Subsequently, one of the 4 things needs to learn about, call it, “virtual” monitor: ListLinePlot, Export, math.exe, or Windows service itself, so that that Windows API call could return some useful data. The question is which one and how, provided that this is possible.

The service you are using will require access to the desktop session.  You might also want to consider upgrading to 13.1 or later.

I am not asking how to run with the access to the desktop session. I can simply run exe under some user name. I explicitly want to run the app as a Windows service. That's what this question is about. Mathematica version is also irrelevant unless 14.1 (which is the newest version as of this date) supports, call it, "virtual" monitor where one could specify a resolution of the monitor for various Mathematica graphics functions.

That is how you run it as a Windows service.  It is a property of the service in the LogOn tab.

This option is only available if you choose Local System Account and that does not work. I've already tried. Perhaps some permissions need to be given to this account to access files here or there? The other part of Windows service, which spawns math.exe, has no problems writing some intermediate files. So, it is not obvious if this is a permission issue for math.exe, and if yes, then which permissions?

Anything involving exporting to a document or image requires the GUI.  The GUI requires access to the desktop.  Also, the GUI in 13.0 and earlier could run into resource restrictions during startup and would inevitably crash.  Hence why I suggested upgrading.  If I recall correctly, the Local System account tends to have access to everything.  So file system permissions should not be an issue.  I know of a couple of instances where users are effectively doing what you are doing inside of IIS service.  That environment tends to be more restrictive, but they were using 13.1+.

OK, I will upgrade to 13.1+ and advise as soon as I have some results. Meanwhile, if you could, please, provide some information about how exactly do the users do that inside IIS service and that works, then that would qualify as an answer. Thanks a lot!

believe it or not, but this thing started to work after upgrading to 14.1. So, it does look like a bug in 13.0. I've also checked what "monitor" is available to a Windows service by calling Windows API at startup and to my surprise it turned out to be a 1024 x 768, which is not what I have and which then results in some mediocre quality pictures rendered by Wolfram. I wonder if there is a way to set that to some higher values. I can't upvote the answer until you make some edits. Thanks for your help.
